# How can I maintain the order of column from database to Dundas

Tags: dundas

The sequence of columns when coming to dundas gets changed.

is there any way to retain order.

I am using Dundas Dashboard V5. The virtual table is getting data from a stored procedure and I am using dataset into data grid for dashboard. The data from the table is in a sequence which retains till virtual table but gets changed from dataset.

Also last few columns returned pivoted data of two year whose month are dynamic and are in sequence

Eg:

```
PIVOT(MAX(AmountCurrency)
      FOR [Month] IN ([Sep2015], [Oct2015], [Dec2015], [Feb2016], [Mar2016], [Apr2016], [Jun2016], [Jul2016], [Oct2016], [Dec2016]
     )) AS MNamePivot
```

Now two problems which I am facing are:

1. The sequence of months which I create in the stored procedure should be retained in dashboard like mm/yy chronologically
2. The month do get change dynamically so the dashboard should show the changed month(At the moment it is showing Old Cached data).

Let me know if this make sense and is there any solution to it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question? What Dundas product are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Have edited and added detailed issue.Thanks for helping :)

Comment: This issue seems pretty involved. You should contact Dundas support.